# java.util.List<android.widget.ImageView>" is not supported error android

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy intentando pasar un List(Desde un activity,AddClothesActivity) para crear una clase(Clothes). Este paso de informacion lo hago en el constructor.

El problema es que me salta un error de compilacion en el que me dice: Field "clothesList" of type "java.util.List" is not supported. donde clothesList es una variable tipo List

**Clase Clothes:**

```
public class Clothes extends RealmObject{


    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;
    @Required
    private String name;
    @Required
    private String description;
    private float stars;
    private List<ImageView> clothesList;

    public Clothes() {
    }

    public Clothes(String name, String description, float stars, List<ImageView> clothesList ) {
        this.id = MyApp.CityID.incrementAndGet();
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.stars = stars;
        this.clothesList = clothesList;
    }
```

**Clase AddClothesActivity:**

Declaracion

```
private ImageView photoGallery;
private List<ImageView> photos;
```

Añado las fotos que hago o cojo de la galería:

```
Uri path = data.getData();
photoGallery.setImageURI(path);
photos.add((photoGallery));
```

Y las paso con el constructor:

```
Clothes city = new Clothes(name, description, stars, photos);
```

Answer (score 2):

Real no reconoce los campos del tipo `List`, tienes que utilizar `RealmList`:

```
public class Clothes extends RealmObject{

    //...

    private RealList<ImageView> clothesList;

   //...
```

---

Debido que `ImageView` no es soportado, cambialo al tipo `byte[]` que si soportado por real. Para convertirlo `byte[]` puedes utilizar la siguiente clase `ImageViewHelper.java`:

```
public class ImageViewHelper
{
   public static byte[] ToByteArray(ImageView imageView)
   {
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();
        return bytes
   }

   public static void bytesToImageView(byte[] data, ImageView target)
   {
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);

        target.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, target.getWidth(),
                target.getHeight(), false)));
   }
}
```

El uso del metodo para convertir byte[] a ImageView seria asi:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
ImageViewHelper.bytesToImageView(aquiLosBytes, img);

// listo, img ya tiene la imagen.
```

Comment: He probado tu sugerencia pero me salta este error: Error:(30, 34) error: Element type of RealmList must be a class implementing 'RealmModel' or one of the 'java.lang.String', 'byte[]', 'java.lang.Boolean', 'java.lang.Long', 'java.lang.Integer', 'java.lang.Short', 'java.lang.Byte', 'java.lang.Double', 'java.lang.Float', 'java.util.Date'. Al parecer no se puede crear una lista de ImageView. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Cual fue el error?

Comment: Element type of RealmList must be a class implementing 'RealmModel' or one of the 'java.lang.String', 'byte[]', 'java.lang.Boolean', 'java.lang.Long', 'java.lang.Integer', 'java.lang.Short', 'java.lang.Byte', 'java.lang.Double', 'java.lang.Float', 'java.util.Date'

Comment: Como `byte[]` es soportado, puedes cambia el tipo a `byte[]` y luego convertir el `ImageView` a `byte[]` a momento de guardar y viceversa al momento de leer.

Comment: ¿Cómo se hace ese cambio?

Comment: Mira mi respuesta actualizada. Puede codigos de como convertir la imagen a bytes y viceversa. Recuerda que esta de parte tuya hacer los campos del tipo de dato de ImageView a byte[].

Comment: Tu propuesta tiene buena pinta, pero sigo teneindo un error, cuando el programa llega a photoGallery.setImageURI(path) deja de funcionar diciendo: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageURI(android.net.Uri)' on a null object reference. el path esta a null¡¡